# Why is hashing failing in LRU Cacheing Problem in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dll, hash, lru

I recently stumbled across an example online for solving the LRUCache problem for interview questions. When I copied the end code into an IDE and compile/run the code, it was giving a KeyError while running through the test code in the main section.

```py
class DLL:
   def __init__(self, key, value):
       self.key = key
       self.value = value
       self.next = None
       self.prev = None


class LRUCache:
   def __init__(self, capacity: int):
       self.head = DLL(-1, -1)
       self.tail = self.head
       self.tracker = {}
       self.capacity = capacity
       self.length = 0

   def get(self, key: int) -> int:
       if key not in self.tracker:
           return -1

       node = self.tracker[key]
       value = node.value

       while node.next:
           node.prev.next = node.next
           node.next.prev = node.prev
           self.tail.next = node
           node.prev = self.tail
           node.next = None
           self.tail = node

       return value

   def put(self, key: int, value: int) -> None:
       if key not in self.tracker:
           node = self.tracker[key]
           node.value = value
           while node.next:
               node.prev.next = node.next
               node.next.prev = node.prev
               self.tail.next = node
               node.prev = self.tail
               node.next = None
               self.tail = node

       else:
           node = DLL(key, value)
           self.tracker[hash] = node
           self.tail.next = node
           node.prev = self.tail
           self.tail = node
           self.length += 1
           if self.length > self.capacity:
               remove = self.head.next
               self.head.next = self.head.next.next
               self.head.next.prev = self.head
               del self.tracker[remove.key]
               self.length += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
   lru = LRUCache(3)

   lru.put(1, 2)
   lru.put(2, 2)
   lru.put(3, 2)
   lru.get(3)
   lru.get(1)
   lru.put(4, 2)
   lru.get(4)
```

With an error message spitting out:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LRUCache.py", line 63, in <module>
    lru.put(1, 2)
  File "LRUCache.py", line 36, in put
    node = self.tracker[key]
KeyError: 1
```

The problem is linked to the line `self.tracker[hash] = node` but I cannot figure out why. Can someone please explain what is going on here? The original posting does not have a comments section, so I have been stuck trying to figure out someone else's code on my own.

Comment: another general question is why do I instantiate the `self.length` to `0` when I have created a `self.head` node of DLL()? Wouldn't that make the length 1 by default?

Comment: This logic makes no sense and guarantees a KeyError every time.`if key not in self.tracker:
           node = self.tracker[key]`. I think you reversed the sense of the comparison.